# How to add custom field next to “Purchased From” column in order view section

Tags: orders, sales-order, admin-panel

In admin panel **Order View** section how to add custom field next to "Purchased From" column

It should look like

**Purchased From:**

Main Website
Main Website Store
Default Store View

**Purchase Channel:**

Facebook

Comment: How to update the data in database? how to create a new column next to "site_name" field

Comment: i have placed file name open that file and updated according to your requirement @Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put your custom messgae from below file

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\info.phtml
```

After line no `65`